# Error while opening shared object: SunGrid Engine

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, sungridengine

My application uses the Sun N1 grid engine through the API DRMAA present as shared object libdrmaa.so
.
I am using dlopen and dlsym to acess functions of the library. That works fine. Now if I try to link
it form command line the executable is built but executing it gives the error " Cannot open shared object file".

Can anyone suggest what  may be the reason. 

I am using g++ 2.95.3 for compilation and the machine is linux x86_64.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and answer are both very confused: if you can link your executable directly against libdrmaa.so, then there is *absolutely* no good reason to also `dlopen` that same library (and presumably call `dlsym()` on its handle as well).